# Resetting Primary Key of Table in Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, primary-key, identity-column, server-explorer

I have deleted all my old table entries i want to reset The UserID (primary key) column of my table in Visual Studio 2010. Kindly guide how to do that.

Comment: TRUNCATE the table to delete all entries and reset the identity at the same time.

Comment: @Malk: where to write this TRUNCATE statement in Vs 2010 environment??

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to run a sql statement (and have proper permissions for it to execute).

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT 
 ( 
    table_name
        [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio Server Explorer is just a client. You want to **reset identity column** value, in server table. Do you fill the difference?! Say between Email and Outlook, Internet and Firefox?

(I hope I've gave you a good enough tip what to google for)

Comment: no not in server table it goes like Server explorer>Database>Tables>Registration(thats My table name) and there is a column in this table UserId which has been set as a primay key ... i want to **reset** its value back to 1 .. how can i do that in **VS 2010 Environment**??